# How to add horizontal swipe gesture on vertical ScrollView?

Tags: android, gesture

I've the layout defined in this form:

```
<ScrollView
--------->

   <RelativeLayout
    ------->
   <!--other n stuffs-->
   </RelativeLyout>
</ScrollView>
```

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033174/1310152) approach to detect swipe. The same is not working for ScrollView. How can I detect left-to-right and right-to-left gesture in this View?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/13095537/1429884 and yes you will definitely face problems inside a scroll view

Comment: @IceBox I tried that, doesn't work :( ... what problems I'll face for `ScrollView` and how can I fixed those?

Comment: It depends on your requirement,I mean if you can put that relative layout outside the context of ScrollView then it will work.

Comment: @IceBox I dont want the relative layout to go outside the context of ScrollView